# dns_get_record query failed

Tags: php

I was trying to create a DNS availability checker, and while testing `dns_get_record()`, some of the results failed.

My code is something like this:

```php
$result = dns_get_record("pitottube.com", DNS_ANY);
print_r($result);
```

Normally, it is supposed to return something in an array (if it's available), or an empty array (if it's not) -- but if I put "pitottube.com", it gives a warning like this:

```
Warning: dns_get_record() [function.dns-get-record]: DNS Query failed
```

Can you help with this?

Comment: I can't bring up 'pitottube.com' in a browser. Could it be that your website doesn't exist?

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII no, that's not my website, I just put some random string.. and try to compare the result with godaddy / whois domain search availability to see if my code work correctly.. based on godaddy and whois, the domain name is not available (taken I assume)..

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.dns-get-record.php#106941

Comment: Mine was failing with `DNS_ANY` but worked with `DNS_ALL`. The php manual page linked in the previous comment does seem a little sketchy about the efficacy of `DNS_ANY`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the specified "official" dns servers for that domain are offline. A whois on the domain gives:

```
Record expires on 12-Apr-2012.
Record created on 13-Apr-1998.
Database last updated on 25-Jan-2012 13:20:24 EST.

Domain servers in listed order:

NS1.DONGMUN.NET              147.46.147.28
NS2.DONGMUN.NET              147.46.147.29
```

and directly querying either of the specified name servers returns failure - they're not pingable either, so there's no official DNS servers available to respond to queries on that domain. Hence your error.