# Better aproache to deal with dns_get_record

Tags: php, dns

The behavior of `dns_get_record`

**query the A record:**

> var_dump(dns_get_record($host, DNS_A));

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  array(5) {
    ["host"]=>
    string(14) "host.name.tdl"
    ["class"]=>
    string(2) "IN"
    ["ttl"]=>
    int(0)
    ["type"]=>
    string(1) "A"
    ["ip"]=>
    string(12) "192.168.17.2"
  }
}
```

**query the AAAA record:**

> var_dump(dns_get_record($host, DNS_AAAA));

```
PHP Warning:  dns_get_record(): DNS Query failed in file.php on line 4
bool(false)
```

I find it a bit strange that no record is returned as false and not as empty array but I guess it's a way to do it.

**Combine it:**

> var_dump(dns_get_record($host, DNS_A + DNS_AAAA));

```
PHP Warning:  dns_get_record(): DNS Query failed in file.php on line 4
bool(false)
```

And here is my question: Is there a better way to query the A and AAAA record with out doing two dns_get_record calls?

Example values for $host

- shaunwagner.com
- digitec.ch

But basically  it's every host without IPv6.

Comment: Can you provide an example for a value of $host that produces what it is you are seeing? If we cannot reproduce what you see, we cannot do much other than say we cannot reproduce it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9008073/dns-get-record-query-failed

Comment: @superduperawesomephpexpert works fine if I only request the A record

Comment: @kainaw add some hosts to the post

Answer (score 0):

After testing it myself,

```
var_dump(dns_get_record($host, DNS_A + DNS_AAAA));
```

Works just fine, This method is also mentioned on :

http://php.net/manual/en/function.dns-get-record.php

Comment: Which url did you use for $host

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternative by using **[bluelibrary/dns](https://github.com/bluelibraries/dns)**

### PHP code

```php
use BlueLibraries\Dns\Facade\DNS;
use BlueLibraries\Dns\Handlers\DnsHandlerTypes;
use BlueLibraries\Dns\Records\RecordTypes;

$records1 = dns_get_record('test.com', DNS_A + DNS_AAAA);

$records2 = DNS::getRecords(
    'test.com',
    [RecordTypes::A, RecordTypes::AAAA],
    DnsHandlerTypes::DIG
);

print_r($records1);
print_r($records2);
```

#### result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [host] => test.com
            [class] => IN
            [ttl] => 0
            [type] => A
            [ip] => 67.225.146.248
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [host] => test.com
            [class] => IN
            [ttl] => 0
            [type] => AAAA
            [ipv6] => ::ffff:43e1:92f8
        )

)
Array
(
    [0] => BlueLibraries\Dns\Records\Types\A Object
        (
            [data:protected] => Array
                (
                    [host] => test.com
                    [ttl] => 0
                    [class] => IN
                    [type] => A
                    [ip] => 67.225.146.248
                )

        )

    [1] => BlueLibraries\Dns\Records\Types\AAAA Object
        (
            [data:protected] => Array
                (
                    [host] => test.com
                    [ttl] => 0
                    [class] => IN
                    [type] => AAAA
                    [ipv6] => ::ffff:67.225.146.248
                )

        )

)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
var_dump(dns_get_record($host, DNS_ANY));
$tmp=array();
foreach(dns_get_record($host, DNS_ANY) as $dns){
    $tmp[$dns['type']]=$dns;
}
var_dump($tmp);
```

Maybe

Comment: Not really since this requests everything not only the A and AAAA record