# How To Echo Multiple Arrays - PHP

Tags: php, loops, echo

I have a list of emails and want to extract each email's domains names and the DNS_MX for each domain. Here's the code I have:

```
<?php
$emaillist = file('list.txt');
foreach ($emaillist as $x) {
    $domain = substr(strrchr($x, "@"), 1);
    $mx = dns_get_record($domain, DNS_MX);
    foreach ($mx as $key1) {
        $mxtarget = $key1['target'];
    }
    echo "$mxtarget <br>";
}
?>
```

**Problem:** When I echo *$mxtarget*, it echoes only the value of the last email on the list but doesn't 
echo the list of the emails before it. However, if I echo *domain*, it echoes the domains for all the emails on the list.

Comment: show your `list.txt` file for better solution

Comment: It's a list of emails as clearly stated in the question.

Comment: https://tehplayground.com/rKBTurNnd2LWKp3O your code is working just move the `echo` inside the inner loop to get all the dns.

Comment: @OmarAbbas From the link, I can see it works. However, if the email lists are in a file like in my case (where i've used *file()* to get the contents of *list.txt* into an array, it doesn't work. Any pointers?

Comment: @OmarAbbas. Kindly check i've updated the code in the link you sent to open a list.txt file on my server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `echo` statement is outside your `foreach` loop.  Placing the `echo` inside the inner loop will echo each MX one at a time.

If you'd rather echo them all at once with a single command, collect them in a variable inside the loop and then echo the whole list.

### Edit:

In order to process your text file as it's currently formatted, you'll need to first remove the line breaks from each element in the array.

```
<?php
  $emaillist = file('https://cardguard.xyz/tools/list.txt');

  foreach ($emaillist as &$email) {
    $email = str_replace(array("\r", "\n"), '', $email);
  }

  foreach ($emaillist as $x) {
    $domain = substr(strrchr($x, "@"), 1);
    $mx = dns_get_record($domain, DNS_MX);
    //$mxtarget = "";
    foreach ($mx as $key1) {
        $mxtarget = $key1['target']; 
        echo "$mxtarget. \n";
    }
  }
?>
```

Comment: No, it isn't. The first foreach is to traverse the emails list, the second foreach is for the specific element address needed for the actual mx after retrieving the whole DNS_MX from get_dns_record()

Comment: @DamilareGabriel So you're intentionally assigning `$key1['target']` to `$mxtarget` repeatedly and you only want to echo the last one?  Why bother with the second loop then? Just move that closing bracket after the `echo` and you'll be good.

Comment: I'm not trying to echo the last one but the whole list.

Comment: That doesn't work. Check [link](https://tehplayground.com/NAvc0Ee5p4L240bL) to see the code and run it. I've linked it to the list.txt on my server.

Comment: The problem was you text file.  See updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach ($mx as $key1){
 $mxtarget = $key1['target'];}
 echo "$mxtarget <br>";
 }
```

Above code should be

```
foreach ($mx as $key1){
 $mxtarget[] = $key1['target'];}
 }
 print_r($mxtarget);
```

Comment: Tried that. It still prints only the mx for the last email on the list.

Comment: Have you added array to **$mxtarget** like ``$mxtarget[]`` as shown in answer? because it gives all targets in array.

Comment: Yes. I have. It just adds an array name and element address to the output.

Comment: If you want to echo the list of the emails, then this array returns it. But if your ``dns_get_record`` not working for some emails then you should read this **https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9008073/dns-get-record-query-failed**

Comment: It's working for all the emails. I'm only working with 5 emails on the list. Whenever i move any of the emails to the end of the list, it prints the *$mxtarget*.