# dns_get_record It fails and I am able to control the error

Tags: php

I am trying to make an application that checks if the domains are registered, for this I use `dns_get_record ()`, but in some domains it gives me the following 
error:

> dns_get_record (): DNS Query failed

```
try {
        $dominio = 'luna.info';
        $dnsArr = dns_get_record($dominio . '.', DNS_NS);
} catch (Exception $e) {

        if ($e->getMessage() !== 'dns_get_record(): A temporary server error occurred.') {
            throw $e;
        }
        $dns = false;
}
if (count($dnsArr) > 0)
    return false;

return true;
```

Comment: Something similar which might give more information - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9008073/dns-get-record-query-failed

Comment: Does this answer your question? [dns\_get\_record query failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9008073/dns-get-record-query-failed)

Answer (score 0):

/* PHP version 7.1.17 - suppress error and check to insure if a non empty array is returned
*/

```
$dnsArr = @dns_get_record($dominio . '.', DNS_NS); // @ suppress errors

// check for empty array (count == 1 is empty array)
if (count($dnsArr) > 1){
   // process when results present
}
```